# Using the same function on two different controllers

Tags: php, function, yii, controller

I have two controllers on my website, let's call them MovieController and ReviewController.

What I want to do is to use one of MovieController's functions inside ReviewController.

The only thing I could think of is to extend MovieController instead of CController. However, it's hard for me to believe it's the right solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least two options

1) Move the function to the main Controller, under `components/Controller.php`

`class Controller extends CController {`

---

2) Have another class extend from the above-mentioned main controller, and put your shared Movie/Review function inside it. Have both MovieController and ReviewController extend from this intermediate controller instead. Perhaps call it `SharedController`:

`class SharedController extends Controller {`

`class MovieController extends SharedController {`

`class ReviewController extends SharedController {`

Answer (score 1):

You can: 
1) create Helper class
2) use Traits/Behaviors
etc..